# JSLint preferred access method in javascript-- dot notation or array brackets?

Tags: jslint

A coworker is running JSLint on our code and fixing the issues that come up.  One change he made was to go from this:

```
document.getElementById(control["value1"]);
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById(control.value1);
```

Is it JSLint's preference to use the dot notation over array brackets?  My understanding from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) is that the brackets are a bit more flexible, and I wondered what the best practices from the field were.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to use `.` notation unless you actually need to pass a variable.

This looks more normal, and also allows the JITter to do more intelligent things.